# how to fix "This ResultSet is closed " error?

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to use two sql query in my java code. the first query retain all row of table2 and the second one get it's rows one by one. I wrote follow code but it face to "This ResultSet is closed, it means rs ResultSet " error. How can I fix?

```
try{
 String sqlSelectTable2 = "SELECT * FROM table2;";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectTable2); 
while (rs.next()) {
            String strLineId = rs.getString(1);
           String strPoints = rs.getString(2);
        String sqlWithin = "SELECT ST_Within(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT( ),ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((443425 4427680, 441353 4427680, 441368 4426075, 443762 4426149, 443425 4427680))', 4326));";
ResultSet rsWithin = stmt.executeQuery(sqlWithin);
} // end while ... **It get error when it is reading second ResultSet **
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping over a result and then running a statement for each iteration, combine the two statements into a single one. That will be much faster (the inner query does not seem to use anything from the outer query anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate PreparedStatement object for inner query

```
try{
 String sqlSelectTable2 = "SELECT * FROM table2;";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectTable2); 
 while (rs.next()) {
       String strLineId = rs.getString(1);
       String strPoints = rs.getString(2);
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
       String sqlWithin = "SELECT ST_Within(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT( ),ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((443425 4427680, 441353 4427680, 441368 4426075, 443762 4426149, 443425 4427680))', 4326));";

       preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlWithin);
       ResultSet rsWithin = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
} // end while ... **It get error when it is reading second ResultSet **
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @Arashm, if it is the solution you needed, then accept it as answer.

Comment: @ Harshit Shrivastava . excuse me. you mean I should have new connection and statement?

Comment: No, connection should be same, but whatever objects you create like resultset, statement object for querying the database should be different.

Comment: i didn't got it yet. the preparedStatemen is null and get error.

Comment: @Arashm, Sorry, didnt looked the whole syntax thoroughly. Updated the syntax. Check this site for more help http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: The SQL for the inner query does not change in the loop. In that case the `PreparedStatement` for the inner query should be create (=prepared) **outside** of the loop instead of preparing it over and over again.

Comment: @ Harshit Shrivastava. it work now. thanks for your time spending on my problem.

Comment: Of course, you should do that. If inner query is immutable, then there is no sense of putting it in to the loop & increasing the execution time of the program. My solution is if you meet a condition like putting your query in inner loop, then you will have to create separate objects.